# How to remove default box outline animation in chrome on touchstart/ hold?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I have this code here:

```
var t

$('#camera').on("touchstart", function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    t = setTimeout(function(){ $("#filters").addClass("reveal-filters"); }, 1000);   
});

$('#camera').on("touchend", function(e) {
    clearTimeout(t);   
});
```

I've successfully disabled the context menu but how can I remove this black box that appears in chrome when you touch and hold?

[image: circle represent tap-hold]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found those articles useful:

- [Disable scrolling when touch moving certain element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348031/disable-scrolling-when-touch-moving-certain-element)
- [Disable Hold Box on ie11 W8.1 Touch Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886014/disable-hold-box-on-ie11-w8-1-touch-device?rq=1)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj583807(v=vs.85).aspx

Unfortunately, the event "MSHoldVisual" seems only to be supported on Edge/IE, I couldn't find a similar thing for Chrome.